# Too many redirect nginx and varnish

Tags: nginx, https, varnish

I'm using **varnish** cache server with **nginx**. I tried to redirect from http to https. I wrote config for redirecting http to https in varnish server.

**default.vcl**

```
 sub vcl_recv {
    if (client.ip != "127.0.0.1" && req.http.host ~ "groundforce.cloud") {
      set req.http.x-redir = "https://groundforce.cloud" + req.url;
      return(synth(850, ""));
    }
   }
sub vcl_synth {
 if (resp.status == 850) {
     set resp.http.Location = req.http.x-redir;
     set resp.status = 302;
     return (deliver);
 }
}
```

My nginx configuration file:

```
server {
   listen  443 ssl;
   listen  [::]:443 ssl;
   server_name  my_server;
   port_in_redirect off;

   ssl                  on;
   ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/my_server.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/my_server.key;

   ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:20m;
   ssl_session_timeout 60m;

   add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
   add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

   location / {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
     proxy_set_header HTTPS "on";
     }
}

server {
   listen 8080;
   listen [::]:8080;
   server_name  my_server;
   root /var/www/html;
   index index.php;
   port_in_redirect off;

   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
   }
}
```

Note: I removed the above default.vcl code then the http and https both working fine. I followed the following [article](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/varnish/use-varnish-and-nginx-to-serve-wordpress-over-ssl-and-http-on-debian-8/).

Answer (score 0):

Relevant information : https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/rewriting-urls-with-varnish-redirection (ie. Use the PROXY protocol if you can, bring supports it.

This looks like an infinite loop, possibly because requests coming from nginx aren't coming exactly from `127.0.0.1` and so `client.ip != "127.0.0.1"` is true.

Try either looking at `varnishlog` to see what `client.ip` actually is, or just add it to a response header in `vcl_synth` and check it value via `curl -v https://groundforce.cloud/` (or anything you are comfortable with, of course.